# Multiple objects to be declared in run-time for retrofit model

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am using tmdb to get details for the tv shows.
It has an endpoint which looks like:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1399?api_key=API_KEY&append_to_response=season/1,season/2,season/3,season/4,season/5,season/6,season/7,season/8
Here, append to response takes the season numbers to provide the details of that season in the same request. This was an example for a tv show with 8 seasons.
If it has lets say 2 seasons, then the endpoint would be 
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1399?api_key=API_KEY&append_to_response=season/1,season/2

Now when creating the model class for handling this request, the problem is that the seasons are returned themselves as objects, and not in an array. So there can be many seasons.

```
{
    "id": ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    "season/1": {...},
    "season/2": {...},
    "season/3": {...}
}
```

Each of these seasons need a new model class for their own, and the number of objects is also variable. How do I handle this?

[Request with 8 seasons](https://pastebin.com/gu5HTpU1)

[Request with 3 seasons](https://pastebin.com/5KZ1ZSp2)

Comment: Take a look on `API` model in [api-themoviedb](https://github.com/Omertron/api-themoviedb) and [themoviedbapi](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/themoviedbapi/) libraries.

Comment: Looked at them both. They don't handle the case of append_to_response="seasons".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for this is just to define your response to be of type `ResponseBody` which looks like this:

```
@GET(value = "/{yourFirstNumber}/tv/{yourSecondNumber}")
Call<ResponseBody> getStuff(@Path("yourFirstNumber") String whateverYouWantToNameThis1,
                            @Path("yourSecondNumber") String whateverYouWantToNameThis2,
                            @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
                            @Query("append_to_response") String appendToResponse);
```

Just make sure you name these number variables to what they are instead of the phrasing I used as I am unfamiliar with the API.

With this, your request call will look like this:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = yourService.getStuff(yourObject);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                L.m("RESPONSE CODE == " + response.code());
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    ResponseBody successResponse = response.body();
                    //This means it was successful (IE a 200)
                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorResponse = response.errorBody();
                    //This means there was an error (IE a 402)
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                //Handle your error here
            }
        });
```

From there you can parse your `successResponse` in multiple different ways.

For example I use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) and a few other methods in [this class](https://github.com/PGMacDesign/PGMacTips/blob/a0258459d1d1f2df05e3fc97e1da9bc89498b22d/library/src/main/java/com/pgmacdesign/pgmactips/networkclasses/retrofitutilities/RetrofitParser.java), but it really depends on how you want to parse it. If you want to convert it into a string, use the `successResponse.string()` (*not a typo, make sure to use string() and not toString()* ) method and convert it from the serialized response into one you can easily use.

Comment: But the problem is how do I make a model with variable number of objects which holds season/1, season/2, season/3, etc? The process of making the requests is fine. But I wanna know how to create a model with variable objects for seasons, which are not in an array as the api returns.

Comment: Can you post 2 different API JSON responses in your question? I can reformat the answer to match if I better understand what the response body schema should look like